# AWS Free Tier Instances - Running two instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can I run a EC2, t2.micro instance & a RDS db.t2.micro instance, parallel & continuously a whole month ? 
Or is it I can only run one of them ?

I know both of them have 750 hours of up time available in the free tier. But I'm bit confused whether it is (EC2 OR RDS) or (EC2 & RDS) in the free tier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are able to run these parallel.

See [free tier terms](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I first read that page you mentioned. But there's no statement saying we can use it that way. So I'm just afraid to get charged while I'm experimenting. Have you used two instances from two services parallel in the free tier without been charged ?

Comment: The Free Usage Tier explains that you have a **certain number of hours** of free usage for a service in a month. How you use those hours doesn't matter. You could run 30 machines for 1 day each, or 1 machine for 30 days, or 750 machines for 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)